# How to place the CDockablePane on CView

Tags: windows, mfc, sdi

This is a empty `SDI` project

[image]

As you see, I need to put the "cdockpane" on the center view, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What do you mean by 'docking on the center view'? Docking is always on the sides/borders.

Answer (score 0):

You have the source code - look at it.

In MFC, the CFrameWndEx implements docking, not the CView class. In your example, you can pull FileView panel out of its container and dock it anywhere in the empty area in the center of your frame (I mean - a the top, bottom, left or right). If you have more dockable panels, you can keep building up taking all the space available for the view...

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You already have all the source code you need - that wizard-generated project is using docking panels (File View, Class View, etc.)